# In Qt, what happens to an object when a thread finishes?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I have a simple `QObject`:

```
class Engine : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Engine(QObject* parent = 0);
signals:
    void finished();
public slots:
    void start();
};
```

An instance `Engine* engine` is stored inside the main window class. When a button is pressed, the following happens:

```
QThread* thread = new QThread;
engine->moveToThread(thread);
connect(engine, SIGNAL(error(QString)), this, SLOT(errorString(QString)));
connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), engine, SLOT(start()));
connect(engine, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
thread->start();
```

My question is, what happens to `engine` after `thread` finishes?  Can I create another thread and move `engine` to that thread, and repeat everything again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happens to engine after thread finishes?

What happens with the object is independent of it being moved to a thread. When you "move" you are not doing a real move, you are just telling to execute some of the code on a thread. The object will get destroyed as usual (out of scope or delete for heap allocated).

> Can I create another thread and move engine to that thread, and repeat
>   everything again?

Yes, as long as the object still exists.

Comment: Note that the connections to the previous thread will still be there, unless you either destroy the thread or disconnect manually.

Comment: When I move `Engine` to another thread, (again) there is an error saying "Cannot move to target thread". Should I somehow disconnect `Engine` from the previous thread?

Comment: @HenricusV. You need to call the moveToThread from the thread that `Engine` is currently in. The first time that you do it, it is still in the main thread, so you don't get any errors. The second time you need to move it from the `thread` that it currently lives in. [See the Warning at the bottom of this section in moveToThread documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#moveToThread). Also, reading [Thread Affinity](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#thread-affinity) is also useful.